# Import flask and mod_wsgi error while deploying flask app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk via CodeCommit

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a `Flask` app using elastic beanstalk called application.py:

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def index():
return "It works!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
application.run(debug=True)
```

I do have `Flask` package in the site-packages and I am using python3.4.

Platform version used is:
 `arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Python 3.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.4.1`

Following is the error log:

```
[Mon Jul 10 14:27:47.022722 2017] [:error] [pid 11504] [remote 
172.31.70.190:32541]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 1, 
in <module>
[Mon Jul 10 14:27:47.022727 2017] [:error] [pid 11504] [remote 
172.31.70.190:32541]     from flask import Flask
[Mon Jul 10 14:27:47.022748 2017] [:error] [pid 11504] [remote 
172.31.70.190:32541] ImportError: No module named 'flask'
[Mon Jul 10 14:28:01.240877 2017] [:error] [pid 11504] [remote 
172.31.46.142:32541] mod_wsgi (pid=11504): Target WSGI script 
'/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jul 10 14:28:01.240931 2017] [:error] [pid 11504] [remote 
172.31.46.142:32541] mod_wsgi (pid=11504): Exception occurred processing WSGI 
script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
```

Comment: Which ``site-packages`` has Flask in it? Are you using a Python virtual environment? Is mod_wsgi compiled for the same Python version/installation as you want to use?

Comment: Yes, I am using a Python virtual environment. The site-packages in Python3.4 has flask in it. Also, mod_wsgi is complied as  "wsgi.cpython-34.pyc" for Python3.4.

Comment: Are you saying that you did a 'pip install' of mod_wsgi? If so, did you disable Apache loading the normal system mod_wsgi module and configure it instead to use the 'pip install' version of mod_wsgi? And how did you set up mod_wsgi to use the Python virtual environment? Show relevant bits of your Apache configuration.

Comment: This what i did  :                                                                                          > python3.4 -m venv myvirtualenv
> . myvirtualenv/bin/activate
(myvirtualenv) > python --version
Python 3.4.4   I did not do pip install mod_wsgi.

Comment: So what configuration did you add to the Apache configuration files, or to your WSGI script file, to have it use that Python virtual environment? Also, is the system Apache module for mod_wsgi compiled for Python 3.4 and that specific Python installation? You can't force a system Apache module for mod_wsgi compiled for one Python installation to use a different Python installation or virtual environment created from a different Python installation.